# Subdivision surface modifier distorts shape

Tags: modeling

My model looks how I want it to as it is, but when I use subdivision surface seemingly random chunks get added or taken away. How can I prevent this?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: You might want to check to see if your mesh has any non-manifold parts to it.  I think I'm seeing some other problems there than just some missing edge-loops.